# Update Column Using Inner Join and Aggregate Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a table that I need to update using the sum of specified values from another table. The table that needs updated is called ***EngTasks*** with a field called *RunStatus*. *RunStatus* can hold 3 values:

- 1 = Not Started
- 2 = In Progress
- 3 = Complete

The table I need to look at is called ***EngTaskLog*** which holds a field called *HoursApplied* and Foreign Key called *EngTaskID*. For each record I need to look at all records in ***EngTaskLog*** and total up all *HoursApplied* where *EngTaskID* = the ID of the ***EngTasks*** record that needs updated.

I tried the following query on a whim but got an error:

```
UPDATE EngTasks
SET EngTasks.RunStatus = 1
FROM EngTasks ET
INNER JOIN
    EngTaskLog ETL
ON
    SUM(ETL.HoursApplied) = 0
```

I don't have a whole lot of experience with queries, so the above code may look absurd to someone with more experience.

I hope the above makes sense and I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: How is RunStatus determined? Do you want to simply update the total hours per EngTaskID  or is there something more complex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UPDATE ET
    SET ET.RunStatus = 1
    FROM EngTasks ET
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ETL.EngTaskID, SUM(ETL.HoursApplied) s
        FROM EngTasks ET
        INNER JOIN EngTaskLog ETL ON ET.ID = ETL.EngTaskID 
        GROUP BY ETL.EngTaskID
        HAVING SUM(ETL.HoursApplied) = 0 ) x ON ET.ID = x.EngTaskID
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the query and got the following error:
_"Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Column 'EngTaskLog.EngTaskID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."_

Comment: Worked great. Thank you for your help. Great job.